Resources to filter and/or rank research papers based on keywords?
I'm trying to make the case for funding at my college's directive board to take an important course in a research tool that requires us to pay for travel and lodging in another town. Even though it's not strictly necessary, I would like to attach a graph or infographic about how this tool has gained in popularity and citations in academia since its inception, but I'm having trouble finding a resource that allows me to create some sort of ranking of the word along research papers in the area.
I'm still a grad student and haven't used Google Scholar that much (I get my papers from Arxiv and other sources) so maybe there's some functionality that I'm missing.
Simply showing some sort of "this many papers have used the tool or cited related papers" or "this percent of papers use the keyword" would be enough.
(I phrased the question in a general sense so anyone with similar issue can find it, but the tool in this case is gem5, a processor simulation tool, and my area is computer architecture)

And, once again, go find your local, helpful research librarian and get introduced to their professional skills and the professional tools already available at your institution.

"Ask your local librarian" should probably be posted as an answer rather than a comment, but it's certainly not unfriendly to suggest a solution to the problem you post about.

I do find it quite pedantic. "And, once again" what is Jon repeating? It's the first time we speak. They are assuming I haven't gone to my librarian already. "Get introduced to they professional skills and ..." yes, I know what a librarian is and what they're good at.
Somehow Jon is assuming I haven't bothered talking to any of them or doing any search at all before posting.
